# Descifrar caligrafía

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, interpretación

[image]

Tengo problemas para descifrar el segundo apellido de la mujer que se llama Isidora que aparece al final del documento. Si me puedes ayudar se lo agradezco.

Comment: Está difícil, sobre todo porque no está clara la primera leta. Lo más probable es que sea Isidora García Tamargo. Otras como Camargo o Mamargo también te van a aparecer en bases de datos peero casi seguro que quiso escribir una T

Comment: Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo leo, **"Isidora García Tamargo"**.

Una vez optado por el apellido "Tamargo" me intereso por descubrir un poco más sobre sus orígenes, por si de alguna manera el apellido "Tamargo" estuviera ligado con algún dato de los que aparecen en el documento.

"**Tamargo**" aunque es un apellido poco frecuente, es apellido originario del consejo de las Regueras, Asturias, y se sabe que una rama muy extendida del mismo paso a **Grado**, precisamente donde esta fechado este certificado. Por lo tanto, bastante común y conocido en la zona, así que lo normal y sin dudas, el apellido al que te refieres y que intentas descifrar sea "**Tamargo**".

Comment: Gracias por el aporte y sí que busqué después de la primera respuesta. Muchas gracias por interesarse.

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti !

Answer (score 1):

Isidora García Camargo. Camargo es un topónimo de la vecina Cantabria.